# Is it possible to turn off automatic line wrapping in MessageBox()?

Tags: winapi

Win32's `MessageBox()` seems to do some automatic linewrapping after the text exceeds a certain width. But this seems to be somewhat erratic and I'm having a hard time figuring out when exactly it occurs. Consider the example text:

```
Hello World this is a test Hello World this is a test Hello World this is a test Hello World this is a test Hello World this is a test
```

I get this result when `MB_YESNO` is set:

[image: One]

When adding the `MB_ICONQUESTION` style, linewrapping suddenly occurs at a different position and it looks like this:

[image: Two]

So it looks like there is a some sort of fixed window width of around 470px after which the text will be wrapped. But this doesn't seem to be the full truth because when using wxWidgets' `wxMessageBox()` function, it suddenly looks like this:

[image: Three]

That's why I'd like to ask two things:

1. Is it possible to turn off automatic linewrapping so that `MessageBox()` will only wrap the line in case there is a newline character in the text?
2. If it's not possible to turn off automatic linewrapping, is there any documentation on when `MessageBox()` will wrap the line because currently this seems to be a little inconsistent and I'm trying to figure out what is the rule here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documentation on how `MessageBox()` auto-wraps long text. The only option it provides you to control how text is wrapped is by placing explicit line break characters in the text itself.

Regardless of word wrapping, if you want to control the size of the dialog, use [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect) instead.  The [`TASKDIALOGCONFIG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-taskdialogconfig) struct has a `cxWidth` field:

> The width of the task dialog's client area, in dialog units. If 0, the task dialog manager will calculate the ideal width.

Comment: I'm a little confused that there is no documentation on this because MSDN says: `If the string consists of more than one line, you can separate the lines using a carriage return and/or linefeed character between each line` Now if there is no control over wrapping, using linefeed characters in the text might be a very bad idea because you can never know where Windows will wrap the text so the text layout might get completely messed up, e.g. if automatic wrapping occurs shortly before a hard-coded linefeed...

Comment: @Andreas "*you can separate the lines using a carriage return and/or linefeed character between each line*" - but that has nothing to do with "automatic linewrapping after the text exceeds a certain width", which is what you originally asked about. That information is not documented.  So yes, you are correct that the dialog content might get messed up if you try to control the line breaks yourself and have long lines that get auto-wrapped, too.  If you need more control over the text formatting, consider creating your own dialog.

Comment: Related information: [Why doesn't my MessageBox wrap at the right location?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110624-00/?p=10343)

Comment: Gotta love how Raymond's blog fills in important detail that the official documentation lacks.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks for the link! That's exactly the explanation I was looking for.